# Android ListView with radio button

Tags: android, listview

```
> I want to change the selected item's checkbox color of listview so that when user selects the item its color gets changed this is my code :

final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvcancelorder);                
//this is my listview
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =     
new ArrayAdapter<String(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, countries); //this is the adapter

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) //this is the item click event
 {    
 selectedFromList = (listView.getItemAtPosition(position)).toString();   
    }});  //this is the selected item from the listview
```

How can I do this ? Please suggest something.
I know to do this thing List view custom adapter but have no idea to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to create your own custom adapter extends from BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter and on selection of item simply change background color of root layout view.

use following link to get know about how to create a listview with checkboxes.
[see here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
//Your button to get selected list
getChoice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getchoice);

        ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries);
        myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
        getChoice.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String selected = "";
                int cntChoice = myList.getCount();

                SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = myList.getCheckedItemPositions();
                for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++){ 
                    if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) { 
                        selected += myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";

                    }

                }

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }});
```

Comment: I didnt get it,,I have asked how to change the color of selected item in radio button...?